# Nested react-navigation deep-linking with expo react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, expo, stack-navigator

We're trying to add deep-linking to our Expo react native app using [Expo Linking](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v32.0.0/workflow/linking/) that opens a specific path within the app using something like this: 
`myapp://home/items/order-details`. However, when trying to use that deeplink url we are only taken to the home screen.

But, when we use this url: `myapp://profile`, it does indeed open the profile screen instead of the home screen. It seems to be working for top-level routes but not the nested ones. Is there a way to get the deeplink url to go directly to the order-details screen using our navigation?

Our App.js looks like this:

```
import {createRootNavigator} from './router';

const RootNav = createRootNavigator();
const prefix = Expo.Linking.makeUrl('/');

export default class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Root>
                <RootNav uriPrefix={prefix}/>
            </Root>
        )
    }
```

This is our router.js

```
export const MenuNav = createStackNavigator ({
    Menu: {screen: Menu, path: 'menu'},
    OrderDetails: {screen: OrderDetails, path: 'order-details'}
    }
);

export const UserCreate = createStackNavigator ({
    Profile: {screen: Profile}
});

export const Tabs = createBottomTabNavigator({
   'Home': {
        screen: Home,
        path: 'home-tab'
    },
    'Items': {
        screen: MenuNav,
        path: 'items'
    }
}, 
    {tabBarComponent: (props) => {
        return (
          <TabBar
            {...props}
          />
        );
      },
        tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
    },
);


export const createRootNavigator = () => {
  return createDrawerNavigator ({
    Home: {
        screen: Tabs,
        path: 'home'
    }, 
    Profiles: {
        screen: UserCreate,
        path: 'profile'
    },
});
```

Comment: `const prefix = Expo.Linking.makeUrl('items/order-details', queryParams)` can you try this?

Comment: @hongdevelop Thank you so much!! Unfortunately, it is still not navigating to the order-details screen!

Comment: Do you add `path` to the back and try again?

Comment: Expo.Linking.makeUrl('path/items/order-details', queryParams)

Comment: @hongdevelop Using `Expo.Linking.makeUrl('path/items/order-details', queryParams)` should I be trying to navigate like this: `myapp://home/items/order-details` or should it include path like this: `myapp://path/items/order-details` or is `path` standing for something else?
When I try to navigate using either of these, sadly it is remaining on the home screen :(

Comment: I'm sorry. I was mistaken. `Expo.Linking.makeUrl('path/home/items/order-details', queryParams)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the navigators are so nested, instead of adding the `uriPrefix` in the `RootNav` on the App.js, try adding it to the tabBarComponent. So, in your router.js you should add the `uriPrefix = {prefix}` to TabBar.  Also, since `order-details` is nested within another stack, it might be necessary to add another stack just for the `OrderDetails` screen since it is already its own screen.
router.js should look like this:

```js
const prefix = Expo.Linking.makeUrl('/');
export const MenuNav = createStackNavigator ({
    Menu: {screen: Menu, path: 'menu'},
    OrderDetails: {screen: OrderDetails, path: 'order-details'}
    }
);

export const UserCreate = createStackNavigator ({
    Profile: {screen: Profile}
});

export const Tabs = createBottomTabNavigator({
   'Home': {
        screen: Home,
        path: 'home-tab'
    },
    'Items': {
        screen: MenuNav,
        path: 'items'
    }
}, 
    {tabBarComponent: (props) => {
        return (
          <TabBar
            {...props}
            uriPrefix={prefix}
          />
        );
      },
        tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
    },
);


export const createRootNavigator = () => {
  return createDrawerNavigator ({
    Home: {
        screen: Tabs,
        path: 'home'
    }, 
    Profiles: {
        screen: UserCreate,
        path: 'profile'
    },
    OrderDetails: {
        screen: OrderDetails,
        path: 'history/order/:orderId'
    }
});
```